# Hibernate query for employee with date

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is my code.. Query working when i search with mysql query(find it in screenshot).But failed with hiberbate query.

```
EmployeeAttendanceMaster masterEmployeeFromRepository = masterEmployeeRepository.findById(employee, date);
    if (masterEmployeeFromRepository == null) {

        System.out.println("SignIn Successfully");
    }else System.out.println("You are already Logged In");
```

masterEmployeeRepository:

```
@Query("select me from EmployeeAttendanceMaster me where me.employee = ?1 and Date(me.date) = ?2 order by me.date desc")
EmployeeAttendanceMaster findById(Employee employee,Date date);
```

[mysql db screenshot in with same query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt2oc.png)

Data with same date there in db..So it shoudnot go through if condition.It should follow else condition.But as long as i tried this it prints "SignIn Successfully"

Thanks advance

Comment: Why do you have `Date(me.date) = ?2`?  Have you tried `me.date = ?2`?  What is the data type for the `EmployeeAttendanceMaster.date` column?

Comment: Date in db is  2016-02-17 11:58:11 .. I want only date ..Thats why I used it In entity table :
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime date;

Comment: What is the full data type of `@Query`?  Are you using Spring Data JPA?

Comment: I didn't get you..What is full data type..??We are using spring and hibernate..

Comment: The full data type of a class is its fully qualified type name.  For example, the full data type of the `String` class is `java.lang.String`, that of the `@Documented` annotation is `java.lang.annotation.Documented` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying me.. org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query for @Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Spring Data JPA `@Query` annotation (as discerned from the full data type you have provided in the comments to your question).  The query you  specify with `@Query` (`select me from EmployeeAttendanceMaster me ...`) must be a valid JPA Query Language (JPQL) statement.  From what I know and remember, JPQL does not have a `Date()` function.  So, your query is invalid because it contains `Date(me.date)` which refers to a non-existent JPQL `Date()` function, even if you can run it directly on MySQL.

You can change your query declaration to:

```
@Query(value = "select * from EmployeeAttendanceMaster where employee_id = ?1 and Date(date) = ?2 order by date desc", nativeQuery = true)
```

This will force the JPA provider (Hibernate in your case) to treat the query as a native SQL query and will be executed on the underlying database without any translation.  You will lose database independence though.

Comment: See the modified query in the answer above.

Comment: This Query working like my previous query.. Though employee with same date is there in db its passing through "if" condition and storing multiple records.. But I want if employee with same date there in db it should follow else condition.i.e query is not working properly